# Smallest number in array

Tags: java, arrays

How do I find the smallest number in an array? The problem with my code is it always print out 0 as the smallest number.

here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise1 {
  public static void main (String [] args){
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Please type the total number of marks: ");
   int SIZE = kb.nextInt();

   double [] marks = new double [SIZE];

    double smallest = marks [0]; 
    for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        System.out.print("Enter the mark: ");
        marks[i]=kb.nextDouble();

         if(marks[i] < smallest) {
           smallest = marks[i];
   }  

  }
  System.out.println("The lowest number is " + smallest);
}
}
```

Comment: Why would your code print anything other than 0?

Comment: Think... what is the value of `smallest` at `double smallest = marks [0];` and then the value of `marks[i]` at `if(marks[i] < smallest) {`?

Comment: @Sortirios: Because user inputs negative number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you create fixed size array. So when you assign smallest, all the item in your array is 0, so it will be 0.

You should change your code to:

```
double smallest;
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter the mark: ");
    marks[i] = kb.nextDouble();

    if (i == 0) {
        smallest = marks[0];
    }
    if (marks[i] < smallest) {
        smallest = marks[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really see how this solves his problem. The `if` statement you put in is the same as what he has above. The only difference is he did it before the loop and you did it in the loop. This is actually less efficient because that if statement will have to be checked `SIZE` times. If I'm wrong, please let me know.

Comment: @LawrenceAiello it only the same when input has value lower than or equal 0, if you do like that guy, and all your input is greater than 0, the smallest will always 0 is the initial value of the fixed array values. My solution for sure that the initial smallest is the first value of array, and not the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Your array doesn't have anything in it. Fill the array with valid values and try it again and see what happens. In Java, [arrays consisting of doubles are initialized according to this spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5), so your whole array currently contains values of 0.0d.